# JS - JSON: adding a keypair in each object by calculating the difference in time now and a timestamp in the JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to store an additional keypair in each object of a JSON array with calculated time.

I have a JSON array with objects, as follows:

```
var arrofobj = [{"id": 1, "timestamp":1545311087282},{"id": 2, "timestamp":1545311148254}];
```

I want to add a keypair to each object in the array with the difference between the 'now timestamp', and the timestamp stored in the JSON objects.

Will it work with a `forEach()` statement, where I can generate the new keypair with a statement such as:

`arrofobj.timestampdiff = (new Date().getTime() - arrofobj.timestamp)`

But I am not sure how?

Furthermore, I want to calculate the diff in minutes of the timestamps stored, and now, sometimes the stored timestamp is 0, then it must also report 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're aware of the `forEach` method, but with that, you're making changes to the original array, if you'd like make a new copy of the array, you can use `map`. Then of course to make 'clones' of the objects within the array by making use of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

### Edit

I've updated it to be more like the answer @Ashish wrote, the way I wrote it was probably more '*beginner friendly*', but this way is just as good, and it's less code to write, which is nice.

```js
const array = [{"id": 1,"timestamp": 1545311087282}, {"id": 2, "timestamp": 1545311148254}];
const now = new Date().getTime();

// New copy.
const newArray = array.map(o => ({...o, diff: now - o.timestamp}));

console.log(array);
console.log(newArray);

// Changes original. 
array.forEach(o => o.diff = now - o.timestamp);
console.log(array);
```

### Edit 2

You may want to play around with the **how** it's working out the difference in minutes, but I'm *assuming* this is what you're trying to achieve?

```js
const array = [{"id": 1,"timestamp": 1545311087282}, {"id": 2, "timestamp": 1545311148254}];
const now = new Date().getTime();

// Difference in minutes.
const diff = time => new Date(now).getMinutes() - new Date(time).getMinutes();

// New copy.
const newArray = array.map(o => ({...o, minsDiff: diff(o.timestamp)}));

console.log(array);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thank you @JO3-W3B-D3V , (and sorry to ask another question), I am trying to change the diff into minutes, but ` const newarr = arr.map(o => ({diff: (now - o.timestamp).getMinutes() })); ` does not work, it says ` TypeError: (now - o.timestamp).getMinutes is not a function `. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jéan I've made a little difference to illustrate how you could do it.

Comment: Wow, this us clever dude! A higher order function as a constant! Never seen this in action! Thank you!

Comment: @Jéan haha, I'm glad you like it! It's nothing complicated, as you can see, I personally like writing my JavaScript in a functional style because I'm just lazy... Haha! :)

Comment: Hi @JO3-W3B-D3V, one more thing... (I will adapt my Q to reflect new), sometimes timestamp = 0, in souch cases I dot not want the minutes calc to be done, I am trying to bring an if statement into your function, as such ` const diff = time => ( if (time === 0) { 
                            0 ; 
                        } else {
    new Date(now).getMinutes() - new Date(time).getMinutes() }); `, but it does not work, how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Array.forEach** as following

```js
var arrofobj = [{"id": 1, "timestamp":1545311087282},{"id": 2, "timestamp":1545311148254}];
let now = new Date().getTime();
arrofobj.forEach(v => v.timestampdiff = now - v.timestamp);
console.log(arrofobj);
```

Comment: Thank you all, @JO3-W3B-D3V, I did not know that forEach adds to the current array, but that is what I need now, will use other options for other use cases. Thanks all !

Comment: @Jéan I'm glad to have share something with you! :) If you're not worried about changing the array directly, then sure, use ```forEach```! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple oneliner approach with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
arrofobj.map(data=> ({...data, timestampdiff: new Date().getTime() - data.timestamp}))
```